# Как вывести значение ship в woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Написано тема, в которой есть прописан шаблон в woocommerce. Как вывести значение ship в нужной части верстки?

```
function ed_get_shipping_info($product_id, $ship_info = false, &$shipping_exists = false) {
if($ship_info==false) {
    $data = WC()->session->get('ed_shipping_data');
}
else {
    $data = $ship_info;
}

$string = '';
if(isset($data) && isset($data[$product_id])) {
  var_dump($data);
    if($data[$product_id]['get_type'] == 'ship') {
        $string .= '<strong>999_Ship</strong>';
        $shipping_exists = true;
    } elseif ($data[$product_id]['get_type'] == 'pick_up') {
        $string .= '<strong>Pick Up At: </strong>';
        $addresses = ed_get_pickup_addresses(ed_get_store($product_id));

        $string .= $addresses[$data[$product_id]['pick_up_address']];
    }
} else {
    $string .= '<strong>Ship</strong>';
}
return $string;
}
```

Результат вывода:

```
999_Ship
```

Т.е. срабатывает первое условие. Сделал var_dump он показывает следующее:

```
array(1) {
    [759]=>
         array(2) {
           ["product_id"]=> string(3) "759"
           ["get_type"]=>   string(4) "ship"
         }
}
```

А мне нужно чтоб выводило значение. Подскажите пожалуйста как в переменную $string поместить значение chip?

Comment: Что в итоге должно выводить ?

Comment: @Даниил, в итоге должно выводить значение, установленное в Fate Rate, а именно 5

Comment: Может данная [статья](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-for-woocommerce--cms-26098) будет вам полезна:

Comment: @Даниил спасибо, очень полезная ссылка

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($data[$product_id]['get_type'] == 'ship') {
    $string = $data[$product_id]['get_type'];
    $shipping_exists = true;
}
```